# How to make a type nillable in a GeoServer SQL view

Tags: geoserver

In our application we have a SQL view defined in the GeoServer ( [gist](https://gist.github.com/ThomasJunk/330484ed1cb16b92a0fc00fd34b76e8e) ) The view works in general fine but has a subtle problem:

There are two values (`gm_waterlevel`, `gm_n_14d`) in the query which could be `null`.
But when the view delivers the according data, I get one correctly as `null` and the other one is `0` (`gm_waterlevel` where `null` would correctly indicate no waterlevel at all). Which made me wonder. Looking at the "Edit Layer" section, I noticed one value being `Double` the other being `Long` (from my Java knowledge both *nullable* types). But one of them is listed as *nillable* and the other is not - which would explain, why `null` ends up being `0`. Is there any way to change that type to *nillable*?

I do not know how the type inference happens here. Is the a possibility to give hints or something?

From a schema point of view, the column `water_level` in the according table is indeed defined as not null, since inserting entries missing this essential information would be wrong. But the result of e.g. above query is totally sound when the result of the join operation is `null`, indicating *no entries yet*. So the inferece of being *not nillable* from the column definition is here not helpful.

From the applications POV there is a difference of having a waterlevel of *0 meters* relative to whatever point - which could lead to wrong assumptions - or indicating *there is no information available* which is totally fine.

The indication of *whether there is a prediction of the waterlevel for the next 14 days `gm_n_14d`* is correct: `null` indicating *no data yet*.

Comment: This seems more of a [dba.se] question than a GIS one. The actual SQL of query is critical to the answer, and cannot be omitted.

Comment: I do not know if a move to DBA is helpful here. From my POV we are talking here about the geoserver side of the problem. From a DBA perspective I see nothing obiously wrong here: The query executes fine and gives the _correct_ information `null`and `null` which is what I expect.

Comment: Then it's a bug report for GeoServer, which should be reproducible with three SQL statements (CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, INSERT).

Comment: Dear downvoter. I accept your opinion on voting this question down. But nevertheless it would be more than fair to comment here to share your reasons to do that. Otherwise it's meaningless because there is no possibility to improve.